# Regex Expression is not working in Fragment

Tags: java, android, regex

This is my code and I have defined `Full_name_regex` globally.
       `String Full_name_regex = "[aeiou]"`. When I am tring to execute the code only the if part is executing even I gave the input as `"aeiou"`

```
Sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String FullName=Full_Name.getText().toString().trim();
        Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(Full_name_regex).matcher(FullName);
        if (matcher.matches()==true)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Text!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Textttt!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: check this out: https://regex101.com/r/rpQ10J/2

Comment: ` if (matcher.matches()==true)` is something weird. Why not just ` if (matcher.matches())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `[aeiou]` means only one char of `[a, e, i, o, u]`.

So if you want an exact match, just remove the brackets.

By the other hand if you just want a text which all chars are in `[a, e, i, o, u]` use `[aeiou]+` which means one or more chars of `[a, e, i, o, u]`.

You should read some tutorials of regular expresions.